# Can Hand-Edited sendmail.cf actually be generated from sendmail.mc?

Tags: centos, sendmail, ubuntu-12.04

I have two CentOS systems, version 5 and 6. Because our firewall has blocked off unsolicited port 25 traffic, we have a little Perl script that logs into our email server as a valid user to send email off our Linux systems. That works fine in CentOS.

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 workstation, which was recently updated, and I had lost the ability to send email off the system until I added this to /etc/mail/sendmail.cf, taking it from one of the CentOS /etc/mail/sendmail.cf files.

```
Msmtpredir,          P=/usr/sbin/SMTPRedirect, F=DFMnSu,
                     S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP,
                     R=EnvToSMTP,
                     T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,
                     A=SMTPRedirect $h $f $u
```

/usr/sbin/SMTPRedirect is a perl script that logs into our email system as a legitimate client without the need for password.

Can Msmtpredir be configured in sendmail.mc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is YES you can and I think it is relatively easy.  I've done a lot of tinkering with sendmail.mc configuration files in the past.....But I'd have to dig into the sendmail.mc documentation to tell you how.  That would be a good place for you to start your research.

From the [sendmail cf.README text file](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/):

"
+--------------------------------+
| ADDING NEW MAILERS OR RULESETS |
+--------------------------------+

Sometimes you may need to add entirely new mailers or rulesets.  They
should be introduced with the constructs MAILER_DEFINITIONS and
LOCAL_RULESETS respectively.  For example:

```
    MAILER_DEFINITIONS
    Mmymailer, ...
    ...

    LOCAL_RULESETS
    Smyruleset
    ...
```

Local additions for the rulesets srv_features, try_tls, tls_rcpt,
tls_client, and tls_server can be made using LOCAL_SRV_FEATURES,
LOCAL_TRY_TLS, LOCAL_TLS_RCPT, LOCAL_TLS_CLIENT, and LOCAL_TLS_SERVER,
respectively.  For example, to add a local ruleset that decides
whether to try STARTTLS in a sendmail client, use:

```
    LOCAL_TRY_TLS
    R...
```

Note: you don't need to add a name for the ruleset, it is implicitly
defined by using the appropriate macro.

"